# Automatically send emails from addresses listed on one sheet when their name is selected from a drop down menu on another sheet

Tags: javascript, email

Hi I have a phone enquiry log that has two sheets - I want to automatically send emails to email addresses stored in a second sheet when their name is selected from a drop down box on another sheet.
I would also like to fill column H with a notifacation 'mail sent'but have limited skills as you all can probably see.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function emailMessage() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var responses = ss.getSheetByName("Enquiry Log");
    var lastRow = responses.getLastRow();
    var values = responses.getRange("A"+lastRow)+":J"+(lastRow)).getValues(); //get the range and values in one step
    var headers = responses.getRange("A1:J1").getValues();
    var recipient = responses.getRange("E"+(lastRow)).getValues();

    var emailSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Emails");
    var names = emailSheet.getRange("A2:A12").getValues();
    var emails = emailSheet.getRange("B2:B12").getValues();
    var subject = "New phone message";
    var message = composeMessage(headers,values);
    var email = '';

    for (var row=0; row < names.length; row++) {
        if (names[row][0] == recipient) {
            email = emails[row][0];
            break;
            MailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject,message);
        }
    }

    function composeMessage(headers,values) {
        var message = 'Please check the Enquiry Log as you have a new message:'
        for(var c=0;c<values[0].length;++c){
            message+='\n'+headers[0][c]+' : '+values[0][c]
        }
        return(message);
    }
};
```